Miniseries based on the book The Count of Monte Cristo
I have seen a near exact reproduction of the book 'The Count Of Monte Cristo'. It was made in a short miniseries when they were producing 'movie events' that lasted a few nights. 
This one was 3 or 4 nights where I possibly missed the first night. The time frame it was made I would say lands around the late 90's; definitely older than 10 years because I know I didn't see it in the house I now live in.
It is not the horrible 2002 movie or the 1998 French version or 1975 movie.
Based on the clear filming, style of consuming, sets and quality, it reminds me of the Arabian Nights miniseries. This had been driving me crazy for years. I can't place any of the actors and IMDB is lacking in any other characters from the book except those versions above.
I have vivid picture from different scenes but I picks some of the ones that rarely show in the known movies.
Gaspard Caderousse at his inn that was filmed in black and blue tones to accent the characters. Later in the miniseries, when he was blackmailing Benedetto, Caderousse was cutting up vegetables(onions) for a meal and turned with a smile and tears in his eyes saying and gesturing to his face "I am weeping with joy." The actor had dark hair, kept close curls and a beard, sounded similar to Topol but thinner face.
Haydée could be seen through a doorway playing a game of tag with her maids. I think she was blindfolded. She sat down before Albert and Dantes, cross-legged on pillows in a naturally lit room and told her story, shown as fully filmed flashbacks.
Eugénie Danglars hacks off her long brown hair in front of Louise d'Armilly before changing for their escape. They are clearly found the next morning in bed together when Benedetto drops down their room chimney. The short chase of Benedetto on the roof and through the small in gave me a great feel for the inn's layout.
This series had the money for ships, horses, costumes and plausible locations. I have this sinking feeling it was named something other than The Count Of Monte Cristo. I would be happy to know I am not the only soul to remember this miniseries.
It was in English. I would say it wasn’t a translated version either. There is a Russian version that I watched clips of and the actors and film style did not match. I have combed through the wiki and even titles of miniseries by decades.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo#Film_and_television

@Paulie_D It was in English. I would say it wasn’t a translated version either. There is a Russian version that I watched clips of and the actors and film style did not match. I have combed through the wiki and even titles of miniseries by decades.

Since you've done a lot of research already, it might help to list the miniseries you can exclude, I guess.

There are 3 other very clear scenes that come mind involving Benedetto. When the count brought the fake Major Cavalcanti and Andrea Cavalcanti to his house, the count slid a rectangular  panel in the wall to spy on them as the acted their way through a meeting. I remember the wall had an intricate mural painting on the opposite wall. The camera paned back and you could see the opening.

Later at the Dinner party, the count has 2 giant tanks rolled in to his left and right to display the fish he had brought in fromy a long distance away. Towards the end of the movie, I remember Benedetto in the prison yard in his tux, trying to polish his shoe with a dirty handkerchief.

I have run through the entire list on the wiki page -.- and IMDB's entire list when just searching Monte Cristo. It is like there was a copyright issue and the film series was banned from lists. It feels like my only hope is to find someone who saw it too.
